# How to convert speech to Text (expect IBM watson API)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

How to convert speech to text, with out using IBM watson API?
that means i need another API for conversion.

Comment: You can try the Google speech to text api https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

Comment: So, what's preventing you from using another API?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Google Cloud Speech : https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/ it provides dictation mode, and you can also select the context of the speech (e.g Medical, School, etc)
2. Bing Speech : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/ it provides dictation mode, and also you can select the context of the speech
3. Microsoft Cognitive Speech : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/ you can make your own language model and accoustic model by sending data training to the azure
4. CMUSphinx : https://cmusphinx.github.io/ it's open source, you can make your own language model, accoustic model, dictionary etc, but you have to handle everything by yourself. (Very Recommended)

Comment: CMUSphinx is a no-internet option! This includes Sphinx4, PocketSphinx, Python PocketSphinx, and PocketSphinx.js.